# Magento 2.1 - activate new laguage

Tags: magento-2.1, localisation

I just did `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT`.

Then I went to `General/Configuration/Locale Options` and set:

- Locale `Italia (Italy)`
- Enable Single-Store Mode `YES`

Then I did `php bin/magento cache:clean` but I still see contents in English. How can I enable Italian as default locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a language pack you need to download and apply one. For Italian you can download a composer packages from Packagist http://bit.ly/2iVPXgw

```
cd <root directory>
composer require magento2translations/language_it_it:dev-master
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Go to Stores -> Configur ation -> General > General -> Locale options and select "Italian (Italy)" as your locale. 
Clear the cache and bingo.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer, it looks promising ;) but I get an error `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                                                     
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/magento-composer-installer): failed to o  
  pen dir: Permission denied    `

Comment: Permissions issue so please ensure your server user is the owner of the files, see magento file permissions topic on devdocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Quick fix which may/may not work but you can try, issue ls -l command in root directory which will show user and group owner of files. Issue command "sudo chown -R user:group ."